# How I get this link inside a #document using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

[image]

I already switch to the `bottomIframe` but I don't know what I should do next

My code at the moment:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  

driver.get("https://dje.tjsp.jus.br/cdje/consultaSimples.do?cdVolume=18&nuDiario=3922&cdCaderno=13&nuSeqpagina=3629")


frame = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="bottomFrame"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```